# Can you style the list of previous submission values for text inputs?

Tags: css

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6xsL.jpg]

Is it possible to use CSS to style the list of previous submission values which appear on text inputs?

Comment: As long as you can get a handle on them, you can style them.

Comment: @DiMono - What do you mean?

Comment: The previous values are html elements. Get some up, look at the html structure to find them, and create a css rule based on that structure.

Comment: You mean form history? I don't think so, but idea is good.

Comment: @Morpheus - Yes, form history, the past values a user has submitted. The image I posted shows the default browser behavior (Firefox) for displaying the drop-down selectable list. Can this styling be overridden with CSS? It seems like a legitimate thing to want to do, but I can't find this discussed anywhere.

Comment: @James Mead me as well, but as I said before, I don't think it's possible. If you try to inspect that dropdown you'll see it has no CSS applied and from this point you can do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using firebug, it doesn't appear that that dropdown gets added to the DOM. Probably handled at the chrome level of the browser.

If you wanted to style something like that, you'd have to keep track of previously entered values on your own. Whether its with cookies or HTML5 localstorage, you could save, per user, values they have previously entered and have Javascript create your own pre-fill list that you could style any way you like.